# Post HTML input tag file data to another input tag file and retrieve in Django views

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm trying to send one `<input type="file"...` value to another `<input type="file"..` using Javascript.

I've created an HTML form and after filling it, I want to review the form. Then submit that form in my **FormFill model** through **views.py**.

So far what I have done is creating 2 different Divs for the same work.

In div1, I'm sending my form data using `action="javascript:reviewForm()"` and in `reviewForm()`, I'm setting all the form data of div1 to div2 form using
`document.getElementById('cfname2').value = document.getElementById('cfname1').value;`

It's setting all the values and then posting it to views.py successfully except my `<input type="file" name="pic2"..` data.

Since python retrieves form POST data using `request.FILES['pic2']`, in div2 I don't have file data to Post.

So far what I've tried is:

```
document.getElementById('pic2').value = document.getElementById('pic1').value;
```

where,
In div1 I have `<input type="file" id="pic1"...`
and in div2, `<input type="file" id="pic2"...`

My **models.py**

```
class FormFill(models.Model):
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='candidates/pics/')
    ...
```

How can I post the div2 image data to views and then to Django models?

**Note:** I don't want to Post the div1 data directly to Django models since I want my users to first review the form that they have filled. And that's why using the concept of 2 Divs.

Thanks in advance.

**Ps.Please ask me if I'm not able to clear the question.**

Comment: You can't do this. For security reasons, browsers don't let you set the value of a file input.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes. I read the same everywhere. But I want if any other solution exists for the same? Like filling my form and then reviewing it and then saving that data to models.

Comment: You don't want to upload the file twice to your server anyway. That would be bad practice. I wouldn't even submit the same data again in the second form, only a confirmation. Just save the file (and all the data of the first form) the first time round as a temp file/temp data and when the second form (or just confirmation) is submitted, make it final in your django code.

Comment: @dirkgroten I'm doing the same about making the second form final and submitting it. But I'm stuck at image tag. As I've mentioned the same in my question.

Comment: As Daniel said it's not possible. But in my opinion your approach is wrong. You **should** submit the first form, because that way you can validate that the data is correct. It would be strange is the user can review everything and then in your back-end you find a validation error and have to say "sorry, there are mistakes in the form please correct them". Which form would that be? The first or the second???

Comment: @dirkgroten Yes, obviously the first form is correct to be submitted. Okay so I will submit the first form directly. Thank you. What I was thinking now, is there any way like I can provide a separate Preview button(just to view the filled form in new window/tab)?

Comment: Yes you can. Either by returning the data to display as a context (so if form was valid, django first returns all the data to display), or by using javascript as you've done but then instead of filling input fields, just fill divs. You can then even display the filename of the first file (you don't need to fill in the actual file input), because your backend already has the file.

Comment: @dirkgroten Got it working now! Thank you so much.